# Append Div Class to Hyperlink Class — then Clone & Append Hyperlink To Container on Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

1. I want to append a div class ('.link-cloner') to a hyperlink class ('.link') when you hover over *any* hyperlink (that has the '.link' class).
2. Then when you click on the appended (.link-cloner) class, I want to clone the hyperlink it was appended to, and append that (link) to #container.

I'm almost there, I just can't make the last part work.

**Codepen:**
http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/JXEEQP/

I tried using find(), closest() & $(this) in various combinations, but I can't make it just clone the hyperlink (not the linkCloner) and append it to the #container.

**jQuery:**

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  /* ------------------------
    Part 1 — WORKS
  --------------------------*/
  // Store link-cloner div in variable
  var linkCloner = $('<div class="link-cloner">Cloner</div>');

  // When mouse hover over any hyperlink
  $('.link').on('mouseover', function() {

    // Append the link-cloner class to the hyperlink
    $(this).append(linkCloner);
  }).mouseleave(function() {

    //on mouse leave, remove link-cloner 
    $(linkCloner).remove();
  });
/* ------------------------
    Part 2 — DOESN'T WORK
  --------------------------*/
  //Then when you click on the appended linkCloner, 
  clone the hyperlink and append it to the #container
  $(linkCloner).on('click', function() {

  // This code is wrong.... 
  event.preventDefault();
  $('.link').clone().append('<li></li>').appendTo('#container');

  });
});
```

Can someone lead me in the right direction? JavaScript or jQuery, either is fine by me (I'm learning both) :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have done just small mistake. Replace your PART 2 with below code :

```
$('.link').on('click', function(event) {

  // This code is wrong.... 
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).clone().append('<li></li>').appendTo('#container');

});
```

Comment: Thank you, but there's one problem, the Clone button (".link-cloner") also gets cloned to the #container... I only want the a href (".link") to get cloned & appended to #container..

Is there some way to detach or just remove the Clone button as soon as the hyperlink is appended to #container? :-)
New codepen with your code added: http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/oxBWGq

Comment: I think I managed to fix it myself, I just added another       $(linkCloner).remove(); to part 2 of the code http://codepen.io/StrengthandFreedom/pen/MyJmQj 

Seems to work, but not sure if this is a good way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
$().drag();
```

for the clone that link to div check jquery documentations

Hope Help